# Trying to access array offset on value of type null on ionic

Tags: php, ionic-framework

when i try to enter login information i get these error on my aksi.php file:

**Notice**:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in

**C:\xampp\htdocs\ionic4login\server_api\file_aksi.php** on line **41**

it's within this line of code :

if($postjson['aksi'] == "add_register") {

```
$password = md5($postjson['password']);
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO login SET 
full_name       = '$postjson[full_name]',
phone_number    = '$postjson[phone_number]',
username        = '$postjson[username]',
password        = '$password'
```

");

Answer (score 1):

i found an answer and it was that i needed to add :
         http://localhost:8100 
in: header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:8100 ');
instead of just using:
     in header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http:*');